# In Kotlin, is it possible to pass `this` as a parameter when call super's constructor

Tags: kotlin

```
interface I {}
open class A(i: I) {}
class B : A(this), I {}
```

I expected codes above will be compiled successfully, but no luck.

Passing a property to super's constructor not works either:

```
interface I {}
open class A(i: I) {}
class B : A(i), I {
    val i = object : I{}
}
```

----- edit -----

Thanks for @Sweeper's comment.

A further question:
is there any programming pattern or best practices can solve such problem:

```
interface I {
    fun onFull()
}

class Eater(private val i: I) {
    fun eat() {
        //...
        i.onFull()
    }
}

class EatThenDrink: Eater(this), I {
    private fun drink() {}
    
    override fun onFull() {
        drink()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not do this, and the compiler is correctly preventing you from doing it. Before the super class constructor runs, `this` is not properly initialised yet.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your comment. So it's just a “compile error”?  The program should work fine if i can guarantee i will not use `this` before super constructor done.

Comment: It's hard to provide advice without a real use case, because this might be an X/Y problem. Something looks like callbacks in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already said in the comments by @Sweeper, when the super class constructor runs, `this` is not fully initialized yet, so this is dangerous and that's why the compiler prevents you from doing this.

It's hard to provide advice without a real use case, because this might be an X/Y problem. Something looks like callbacks in there, which might call for a different approach.

The current approach is hard to understand without more info about the real domain. For instance, you're mixing composition and inheritance here. Why do you want `EatThenDrink` to be an `I`, but not `Eater`?

Note that you could theoretically do this completely with inheritance (**I'm not saying that you *should***):

```kotlin
interface I {
    fun onFull()
}

// this could even be an interface depending on whether you have state
// and depending on what your actual case represents semantically
abstract class Eater : I {
    fun eat() {
        //...
        onFull()
    }
}

class EatThenDrink: Eater() {
    private fun drink() {}
    
    override fun onFull() {
        drink()
    }
}
```

Or you could also maybe use composition completely, but it would be good to know the domain a bit more for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EatThenDrink` can hold an implementation of interface `I` and also pass it to `Eater`:

```
interface I {
    fun onFull()
}

open class Eater(private val i: I) {
    fun eat() {
        println("eat")
        i.onFull()
    }
}

class EatThenDrink(private val drinker: Drinker = Drinker()): Eater(drinker), I {
    class Drinker : I {
        override fun onFull() {
            println("drink")
        }
    }

    override fun onFull() {
        drinker.onFull()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val e: Eater = EatThenDrink()
    e.eat()  // Prints "eat" and then "drink"
}
```